# SWAY + gstreamer on IMX8MP (Only wayland)

Tags: linux, gstreamer, yocto

I'm trying to replace the Weston compositor with Sway on an IMX8MP device. As part of this effort, I've included the Sway package for kirkstone = L5.15.52_2.1.0
sway version= 1.7-5543acff (Jan 22 2022, branch 'v1.7')
wlroots version 0.15.1

in my Yocto build, as shown below:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " sudo sway "
```

Additionally, I created a new user because Sway doesn't support logging in as the root user, and I added this new user to the necessary groups:

```
inherit extrausers
PASSWD="$5$9gounUy.ZkcjiF4H$/Xy3R25TknKrWmv/rCOJfXuDE9wecgyaVilSEymEF1C"
DEV_PASSWD="$5$C6cr07SRVZhrxjIm$2OOBCoEQ.IFORLhzc1KGgXaIqU3ru1Lr9gWYvzeR8E8"
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -p '${PASSWD}' root;
    useradd -m -p '${DEV_PASSWD}' -d /home/dev dev;
    groupadd devs;
    usermod -a -G sudo,video,tty,input,devs dev;
"
```

Running GStreamer without initiating Sway works fine, and VPU support is confirmed to be available. I modified the permissions with the following commands:

```
sudo chgrp video /dev/mxc_*
sudo chmod 660 /dev/mxc_*
```

Here's the GStreamer command I used:

```
sudo -E gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=<filename.mp4>
```

This setup operates smoothly, although there's a scaling issue that I'm currently overlooking.

However, when attempting to execute the same command within Sway, I encountered issues. Below are the steps I took:

Start seatd with the non-root user:

1. start seatd : sudo seatd -u dev &
2. Launch Sway: sway &
3. Set the Wayland display: export WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-1
4. Run the GStreamer command: gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=<filename.mp4>

In this scenario, the frame rate drops to 1.2 FPS, unlike the 30 FPS achieved outside of Sway. Attempting to launch GStreamer with sudo -E results in Sway crashing and the display turning off.

Below are the logs from running the GStreamer command and the kernel logs

```
(GStreamer logs)
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...

====== AIUR: 4.7.1 build on Jul 19 2022 06:15:03. ======
Core: MPEG4PARSER_06.20.06 build on May 7 2022 07:52:31
file: /usr/lib/imx-mm/parser/lib_mp4_parser_arm_elinux.so.3.2
Track 00 [video_0] Enabled
Duration: 0:00:30.033333000
Language: und
Mime:
video/x-h264, parsed=(boolean)true, alignment=(string)au, stream-format=(string)avc, 
width=(int)1920, height=(int)720, framerate=(fra
Track 01 [audio_0] Enabled
Duration: 0:00:30.549333000
Language: und
Mime:
audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, channels=(int)2, rate=(int)48000, bitrate=(int)2276, 
stream-format=(string)raw, codec_data=(buffer)11
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/1000) is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 1000! (This 
could e.g. happen if you try to connect to a non-root Pul)

====== BEEP: 4.7.1 build on Jul[ 4572.364687] remoteproc remoteproc0: powering up imx- 
dsp-rproc
19 2022 06:15:03. ======
Core: DSP decoder Wrapper build on [ 4572.376352] remoteproc remoteproc0: Booting fw 
image imx/dsp/hifi4.bin, size 804421
May 19 2022 08:49:06
file: /usr[ 4572.387226] imx-dsp-rproc 3b6e8000.dsp: Allocated carveout doesn't fit 
device address request
/lib/imx-mm/audio-codec/wrap/lib_[ 4572.397921] imx-dsp-rproc 3b6e8000.dsp: Allocated 
carveout doesn't fit device address request
dsp_wrap_arm_elinux.so
[ 4572.408902] remoteproc remoteproc0: bad phdr da 0x92400000 mem 0x408cc
[ 4572.417484] remoteproc remoteproc0: Failed to load program segments: -22
[ 4572.424384] remoteproc remoteproc0: Boot failed: -22
Error: Invalid argument
remote proc is not ready

====== BEEP: 4.7.1 build on Jul 19 2022 06:15:03. ======
Core: AAC decoder Wrapper build on Jul 25 2022 15:45:05
file: /usr/lib/imx-mm/audio-codec/wrap/lib_aacd_wrap_arm_elinux.so.3
CODEC: BLN_MAD-MMCODECS_AACD_ARM_03.09.00_ARMV8 build on Jul 25 2022 10:05:48.

====== V4L2DEC: 1.20.0 build on Jul 28 2022 06:57:16. ======
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ... 
g pipeline to PLAYING ...

(kernel logs)
[ 4572.408902] remoteproc remoteproc0: bad phdr da 0x92400000 mem 0x408cc
[ 4572.417484] remoteproc remoteproc0: Failed to load program segments: -22
[ 4572.424384] remoteproc remoteproc0: Boot failed: -2
[ 4573.789319] drm_panel_disable
[ 4573.792318] panel_simple_disable enabled=1
[ 4573.796549] panel_simple_disable - Backlihgt(off) to stop lvds signal time - STBYB 
pull L to RSTB time: 167
[ 4574.124807] imx8mp_ldb_encoder_disable
[ 4574.128692] drm_panel_unprepare
[ 4574.131832] panel_simple_unprepare prepared=1
[ 4574.136308] panel_simple_unprepare - Restart VCC time: 500
[ 4574.678516] drm_panel_prepare
[ 4574.681512] panel_simple_prepare prepared=0
[ 4574.685836] imx8mp_ldb_encoder_enable
```

It appears that while GStreamer commands run correctly without Sway, integrating them into a Sway session leads to performance degradation and crashes. Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It probably does not support the GPU features and other acceleration features of the iMX8. Maybe you have to look at what Freescale did with [weston_10.0.1.imx.bb](https://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-freescale/tree/recipes-graphics/wayland/weston_10.0.1.imx.bb?h=kirkstone#n173) and adjust `DEPENDS` and compilation flags.

Comment: I checked with the sway maintainer and they stated that wlroots does not support the proprietary drivers. So for that, I need to use the Etnaviv drivers.